# Parsing Laravel Config in PHP

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

Laravel has config files of which are great for storing variables that are accessed from every page on my website. The current app.php config file contains:

```
return [
    'name' => 'This is a name',
    'slogan' => 'This is a slogan!',
    'primary_color' => '#cc0202',
    'secondary_color' => '#990000',
    'tertiary_color' => '#FFFFFF'
];
```

This is just an associative array that of which can be accessed by Blade code using:

```
{{ config('app.primary_color', '#cc0202') }}
```

However I wish to use the data from within a .php file that is in the public folder. Files that are in the public folder can not use Blade. What would be the best way to get this data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use your Laravel's config in PHP files in `public` directory just require this file by

```
$config = include '../config/app.php'; // Go back to main catalog
                                       // and go to config catalog
```

and use it as normal array.

For example

```
echo $config['primary_color'];
```

But in my opinion is very bad practice to put PHP files in `public` catalog if you are using a framework.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<?php $variable = config('app.primary_color', '#cc0202') ?>
```

Comment: Ok. What you want to do with that php file, are you using it for email or something. if you can tell then i can suggest you a solution.

Comment: The php file is just a config file storing variables that are accessed by pages all over my website. It would be convenient to have them all in one place but I can't access the config() function from inside the public folder

Answer (score 0):

To access and print:

```
echo config('app.primary_color');
```

To set data:

```
config(['app.primary_color' => '#cc0202']);
```

Comment: I just tested it, and it works fine at my end. Tried in index.php in public directory.

Comment: Nope just tells me the config function is undefined. Any idea on what file the config() function could be found??

Comment: Which file are you using it in? And what is the path of the file relative to public directory?

Comment: The config file is "config/app.php" and the php file is "public/css/style.css.php"

Comment: @EnayetHussain Why would you want it on your public directory? The configuration system of Laravel specifically looks for config files inside the `[PROJECT_ROOT]/config` directory.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use a custom service provider instead ?

From laravel documentation:

> Service providers are the central place of all Laravel application bootstrapping. Your own application, as well as all of Laravel's core services are bootstrapped via service providers.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/providers , You can see this helpful tutorial on laracasts to: https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-5-fundamentals/episodes/25